# What is the MS Win32 API to know a folder is shortcuts?

Tags: winapi, directory, shortcut

In Vista and Windows 7, there are many folders are shortcuts, like "C:\Users\Administrator\Application Data", use FindFileFirst serial API can enumerate all files under the folder, however we can NOT open it in Windows Explorer, I will also get error while call `CreateFile` to open the folder or the file enumerated by `FindFileFirst` serial API. I want to know what is the MS Win32 API to know a folder is shortcuts? Is `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT` flag using for this kind of folder?

Comment: How does a bear know what apples is?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have known the answer, see on this blog.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041227-00/?p=36883

Answer (score 0):

Hm looks as if there is not API there to check that.... I may be wrong of course
here's has someone written about it's format:
http://www.i2s-lab.com/Papers/The_Windows_Shortcut_File_Format.pdf

so maybe opening the file and finding the GUID is what you have to do?

Regards
Friedrich